# How to override line-height from parent element

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a problem with changing the line-height of a child element.
My goal is just to reset line-height to normal value instead of using the higher value of its parent.

```
a{ line-height:100px; }
a small{ line-height:10px; //or normal }
```

So I want the line-height of `small` to normal but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[Small Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pae871az/1/)

Comment: How do you expect this to work? How would you expect `<a>Some Text<small>Small Text</small>More Text</a>` to look? Should the entire line's line-height be reduced?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use:

```
small {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1; /*or whatever you like.*/
}
```

You need `inline-block`, as `<small>` is inline by default, and so inherits its parent's line height.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pae871az/2/)
i just added `display:inline-block`

```
.first small{
  line-height:normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
```